# My icon font inside input text is working fine , except for internet explorer

Tags: html, css

I have an input with  "email icon font" inside aligned to left, and I already have this working fine.

However in **internet explorer** my icon font stays more to bottom , and stuck with the text "Enter your email".

Do you know any trick to fix this? (Im testing in internet explorer 10)

I have my code in this jsfiddle, but here is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/Kmx3L/1/

And this is my html:

```
<div id="col" >
    <h1>Tile</h1>

    <form>
      <label id="email_newsletter_container">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
          <input type="text" id="email_newsletter" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email..." />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
          <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" src="" />
      </label>
    </form>
</div>
```

In internet explorer Im getting this:

[image]

And in Chrome and mozilla is working fine, as you can see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of IE will not support the placeholder attribute, but you might use jquery instead.
Try this solution

http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html